# OpenSUSE "fstab" "mount" "An error occurred while accessing" "the system responded: mount: only root can mount"

Tags: network-shares, samba, opensuse, fstab, dolphin-file-manager

Gentlemen,

I trying to mount a network share at OpenSUSE's boot, when I try to access the folder where the share is mounted (using Dolphin) the system returns me the following error (edited):

**"An error occurred while accessing ..." "... The system responded: mount: only root can mount ..."**

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue use the parameters "x-systemd.automount" and "cache=none" in the share to be mounted using fstab.

Example:

```
//192.168.56.1/Data/DEV/ /home/brlight/DEV/ cifs auto,x-systemd.automount,cache=none,users,username=eduardo,password=questor 0 0
```

I'm not sure about that, but it seems that this problem occurs for two reasons: 1 - The network is unavailable when the system tries to mount the share; 2 - When you using the parameter "x-systemd.automount", the UI (KDE) try to mount the share when needed or inherits some kind of permission to mount the share!

I appreciate comments and possible corrections!

Thanks to **kaipee**!
Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1168782